# How to show current user's location on simulator

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ios-simulator

Not able to show the current user location on simulator, I'm having `iOS 9` and `X- Code 7.2`.

I've tried this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;


- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;

    self.mapView.delegate =  self;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    self.mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;
    self.mapView.zoomEnabled=YES;

}
```

But no location indicator is appearing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way: At the bottom of Xcode's source window you will find the location arrow when running the debugger. You can select any of the predefined locations or a self-defined location:

[image: Select simulated location]

To define your own location, create a GPX file, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode">
    <wpt lat="52.530426" lon="13.345692">
        <name>Berlin</name>
    </wpt>
</gpx>
```

Of course, this is also available via the menu:

[image]

Comment: I've set the location by arrow in source window,but user location didn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but simulator can no get current location so use real device.you get your current location in the map...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to show your simulator location is to simulate it by custom latitude and longitude and change it all the time when you want to show another user "location" or use real device.

Comment: @ jjj05555 :  I even set custom latitude : 51.50998 and longitude : -0.1337 but still no success i.e. there is no user location at simulator

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add two things. You must add the CoreLocation framework from the center, and then in your ViewController.h, make sure you import CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h.

Comment: It'll be helpful if you could provide the code snippets for the same.